# How to include Java classes when compiling from Command Line?

Tags: java, command-line

I've usually used an IDE for my Java programs but I've recently switched to the Command Line.

I created several classes that are in the same directory as my "main" program that I wish to compile.  However, the command 'javac -cp test.jar ColorTester.java' yields:

```
ColorTester.java:24: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class IntToColor
location: class ColorTester
      IntToColor colorFunc = new ModThreeToColor(testColor,
      ^
```

My classes IntToColor and ModThreeToColor have both been compiled into class files, but it's still not making a difference.

The IDE had always taken care of this for me, so as you can imagine I'm quite confused.

Thank you.

Comment: Where `IntToColor` is located? in which package?

Comment: Are you sure `IntToColor` and `ModThreeToColor` classes are compiled on *test.jar* or just in the same file directory where it is `ColorTester`?

Comment: You need something like javac -cp test.jar:location_of_IntToColor.class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
java -classpath <here> Program
```

Replacing `<here>` with the list of classes and/or jars and/or packages that make up your classpath, separated by the `:` character on Unix (or the `;` character in Windows). There's plenty of documentation online, for example read this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/classpath.html).

Answer (score 1):

include the current directory in the command line class path.

`javac -cp test.jar:. ColorTester.java`